# Readonly variable for positional parameter array $@

Tags: bash, shell, arguments, parameter-passing

Bash has a special variable, `$@`, which stores all parameters sent to a script or function into an array. How do I store the value of this variable into a read-only array?

Say I have a script `/home/jason/bourne`:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

declare -ar Args="$@";
```

Running it throws this error:

```
$ /home/jason/bourne --help memory;
/home/jason/bourne: line 3: Args: readonly variable
```

Is this a syntax mistake or is this not possilbe in bash?

---

Halfway through writing this I figured out the solution. I think it's a helpful question, so I'll post it with an answer.

Answer (score 2):

## Solution

To store the `"$@"` variable as an array, you need to wrap it with `()` like you would with a literal array.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

declare -ar Args=("$@");

for arg in "${Args[@]}"; do
    echo "${arg}";
done;
```

Example output:

```
$ /home/jason/bourne --help memory "quoted phrase";
--help
memory
quoted phrase
```

**NOTE:** `$@` should **always** be wrapped with `""`. *(There's probably an exception to this rule, but at least 99.9% of the time it should be followed.)* In this case, use `("$@")` and not `($@)`.

## Explanation

To create a literal array from scratch in bash, you would do this:

```sh
declare -ar array=("a" "b" "c d");
```

The `"$@"` variable expands to a list of strings with each string wrapped in quotes. Wrapping this list with `()` will turn it into a bash array.

```sh
declare -ar array=("$@");
```

For example, if `"$@"` expands to `"a" "b" "c d"`, then `("$@")` will become `("a" "b" "c d")`.

```
"$@" == "a" "b" "c d"
("$@") == ("a" "b" "c d")
```

## Example

Here's a side by side code example.

Setting the `/home/jason/bourne` script to this:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

declare -ar array=("$@");
for val in "${array[@]}"; do
    echo "${val}";
done;
```

will output this:

```
$ /home/jason/bourne "a" "b" "c d";
a
b
c d
```

Setting the `/home/jason/bourne` script to this:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

declare -ar array=("a" "b" "c d");
for val in "${array[@]}"; do
    echo "${val}";
done;
```

will output the same thing:

```
$ /home/jason/bourne;
a
b
c d
```

Comment: Note that `(...)` is not involved in the expansion at all. `"$@"` expands to a sequence of words *inside* `(...)`, and the contents of `(...)` are assigned as elements to the array parameter.

Comment: @chepner Nice catch on my mistake of using `$@` instead of `"$@"`.  I added a note to point it out so that someone else won't make the same mistake.